# A bug while displaying permissions in SU56

Tags: permissions, sap-basis

Because I could not create some objects in SAP, I was checking my permissions using the `SU56` transaction.

I realized that 2 permissions had the same text (roughly translated from German)

> Permission T-EP050778**07**: 9O,9W,9T create, delete
>   Permission T-EP050778**09**: 9O,9W,9T create, delete

However, when expanding the permission, I can see that the objects listed under `OTYPE` are different:

> OTYPE for T-EP050778**07**: 9E, 9O, 9T, 9W
>   OTYPE for T-EP050778**09**: 9M, 9O

[image: SAP SU56 permissions]

Is that a bug in SAP or is there something wrong with my transport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper line (next to the generated profile name) is a text that is entered manually when maintaining the profile or role. It is not kept in sync with the contents automatically - if the person maintaining the profile or role does not do so, it can easily get out of sync, as it did in your case. For the actual authority check, only the technical values (next to the field names) matter.